# ffmpeg read video height and width is not correct?

Tags: video, video-streaming, ffprobe

I find the ffprobe read video info is not correct.
The command is:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -print_format json -show_format -show_streams xx.mp4
```

[image]

But The video real info is 405x720 size.
That is in my computer infomation:
[image]

Comment: Share full ffprobe readout.

Comment: Is the video just 29 seconds? Maybe share a link to this short file for analysis. It's possible the video picture (H.264 codec) is in 405 x 720 but the MP4 container has a header where the info was put in as 1280 x 720... What happens when you try: `ffmpeg -i xx.mp4 -c:v copy xx_video.h264` now check the picture size of the H.264 video file in FFprobe and tell us.

Comment: @VC.One I mean, the video size read from ffprobe is wrong，about the width,height of video

Comment: I also observed this now. @zui-coding hw were u able to solve this